# Extract all possible longest paths from a tree using Python

Tags: python, graph, python-2.7, tree, pygraphviz

I have a keyword tree generated by using Pygraphviz as shown below. I have the edges of the tree as a list of tuples. I am looking for an algorithm or the best way to extract all possible longest paths from this tree such that it covers all possible relationships.

Since I was using Pygraphviz, I was looking for a direct and easy method to accomplish this. But it looks like Pygraphviz doesn't have an option for this.

```
edges = 
[('Sara', 'chocolate'),
('chocolate', 'loves'),
('oranges', 'chocolate'),
('Jessi', 'chocolate'),
('best', 'best'),
('friends', 'chocolate'),
('Aron', 'chocolate')]
```

[image]

**Expected Result:**

```
[['Sara', 'chocolate', 'loves'],   
 ['oranges', 'chocolate', 'loves'],   
 ['Jessi', 'chocolate', 'loves'],  
 ['friends', 'chocolate', 'loves'],  
 ['Aron', 'chocolate', 'loves'],  
 ['Sara', 'chocolate', 'oranges'],  
 ['Sara', 'chocolate', 'Jessi'],  
 ['Sara', 'chocolate', 'friends'],  
 ['Sara', 'chocolate', 'Aron'],  
 ['oranges', 'chocolate', 'Jessi'],  
 ['oranges', 'chocolate', 'friends'],  
 ['oranges', 'chocolate', 'Aron'],  
 ['Jessi', 'chocolate', 'friends'],
 ['Jessi', 'chocolate', 'Aron'],  
 ['friends', 'chocolate', 'Aron'],
 ['best', 'best']]
```

**My current code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
edges = [('Sara', 'chocolate'),
         ('chocolate', 'loves'),
         ('oranges', 'chocolate'),
         ('Jessi', 'chocolate'),
         ('best', 'best'),
         ('friends', 'chocolate'),
         ('Aron', 'chocolate')]
neighbors = {}
rev_neighbors = {}
for edge in edges:
    neighbors[edge[0]] = edge[1]

for edge in edges:
    neighbor = neighbors.get(edge[1])
    if neighbor:
        print edge[0], edge[1], neighbor

v = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in sorted(neighbors.iteritems()):
    v[value].append(key)
for key, value in v.iteritems():
    if not len(list(itertools.combinations(value, 2))) == 0:
        for item in list(itertools.combinations(value, 2)):
            print item[0], key, item[1]
```

P.S.: Please neglect the number xlabels.